# Build TensorFlow Lite in Docker

Tags: docker, tensorflow-lite

I am following the tutorial to build TensorFlow Lit from tensorflow website (https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_arm). When I am running the following command:

> bazel build --config=elinux_aarch64 -c opt
> //tensorflow/lite/c:libtensorflowlite_c.so

in TensorFlow Docker, I am getting this error:

> ERROR: The 'build' command is only supported from within a workspace
> (below a directory having a WORKSPACE file).

I install Bazel from the following documentation https://docs.bazel.build/versions/4.2.1/install-ubuntu.html.

I google it and can not find any solution for my problem. Thank you for guiding me in solving this problem.

Comment: Hi. Check this article. https://farmaker47.medium.com/building-tensorflow-lite-support-library-with-docker-1e0ac0abda7 You will find some ideas there that may be of help. Also it includes a github repo with colab notebook for building various libraries with Bazel but no Docker.